# TraceQL query to find traces containing one span but not another

Tags: tempo

I'm trying to find "broken" traces where one span was reported but another one wasn't.

I've found a workaround, but it is quite ugly and I think it should be possible to do in a nicer and more robust way:

```
{ name =~ "start|finish" } || { name = "finish" } | count() = 1
```